# What is the easier way to know if a type param implements an interface in c# 2.0?

Tags: c#, reflection, types

For example, given a type param method i'm looking for something like the part in bold

> void MyMethod< T >() {
>   if ( **typeof(T).Implements( *IMyInterface* )** )
>   {
>
> ```
>   //Do something
> ```
>
> else
>
> ```
>   //Do something else
> ```
>
> }

Anwers using C# 3.0 are also welcome, but first drop the .NET 2.0 ones please ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Type.IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx)

```
if(typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
{
  // something
}
else
{
  // something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
if (typeof (IMyInterFace).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
```

should also work: but i don't see an advantage...

Answer (score 0):

Ï've just tried using

```
if( typeof(T).Equals(typeof(IMyInterface) ) 
     ...
```

And also works, but your answer seems more robust and was what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: It does?  it should only work of T is specifically IMyInterface

Comment: It worked for me in my specific case, but the behavior is the one you describe: it doesn't work if you want to know if an object implements IMyInterface, but to assert that the type T is an IMyInterface.
Thanks for the correction!